# How to make background to stage in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html5

```
   var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 490,
    height: 300,
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
```

I want to make a default image to a stage to be the background of the stage.
i'm using kineticjs .

Comment: I have no experience with Kinetic, but to help others answer: What have you tried? What's a "default image"?

Comment: my default image in 490*300 i add it using css but i don't want that i want to draw on the stage using kinetic

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this:
1. Assign a background image to the `div` container using CSS.
2. Create a background layer and add an image that takes up the whole layer.

An example of (2) might be:

```
var background = new Kinetic.Layer();
var bgImage = new Kinetic.Image(...);

layer.add(bgImage);
stage.add(background);
```